# Advice on inheritance / architecture in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, design-patterns, module, refactoring

In order to access to my collections in mongodb, I don't use a third party framework, I use the nodejs mongodb package directly. To do so, for each of my collections in the db, I create a **model** file that look like this :

```js
const Table = "Home";

let driverPromise;

module.exports = function(driver) {

    driverPromise = driver;

    this.getById = getByIdAsync;

    this.update = updateAsync;

    this.getByIdAsync = getByIdAsync;
    this.updateAsync = updateAsync;
    this.deleteAsync = deleteAsync;
    this.deleteAllAsync = deleteAllAsync;
    this.findAllAsync = findAllAsync;
    this.findOneAsync = findOneAsync;
    this.saveAsync = saveAsync;
};


function getByIdAsync(_id) {
    return driverPromise
        .then(driver =>  driver.getByIdAsync(Table, _id))
}

function updateAsync(value) {
    return driverPromise
        .then(driver =>  driver.updateAsync(Table, value, value._id));
}

function deleteAsync(_id) {
    return driverPromise
        .then(driver =>  driver.deleteAsync(Table, _id));
}

function deleteAllAsync(criteria) {
    return driverPromise
        .then(driver =>  driver.deleteAllAsync(Table, criteria));
}

function saveAsync(value) {
    return driverPromise
        .then(driver =>  driver.saveAsync(Table, value));
}

function findAllAsync(criteria) {
    return driverPromise
        .then(driver =>  driver.findAllAsync(Table, criteria));
}

function findOneAsync(criteria) {
    return driverPromise
        .then(driver =>  driver.findOneAsync(Table, criteria));
}
```

The name of the Collection, different for each file, is define in the `cont Table`, and then comes the classic CRUD functions, shared in all the **model** files. What is then exported is... well, I don't know exactly what is is, but it works o_O

To use those files, I would first create, at init time, an instance of it `cont home = new Home(driver)` and then use it in my app like `const result = await home.findOneAsync({name : 'toto'})`
That works fine....

The probleme is, I do this for each collection, meaning that I have a bunch of file that looks exactly the same only difference is the name of the collection! That's enought of a concern already, but also if I want to add a method like 'aggregateAsync' I have to update all the files :'( of course I still need some flexibility because some collection have extra methods, like the `User` that has bcryptjs capabilities, or `Orders` where I added a special aggregation pipeline for the reporting....

So my question is, how can I implement a better design pattern that would mutualise the base function (getById, findOneAsync...) and where I can create kind of *subclasses* that *inherits* those function but with each their own collection name and can possibly be *extended* with some extra functions?

Comment: The table name should not be part of the class, it should be part of the instance. Even with your current code, calling `new Home` multiple times doesn't work - and doesn't make sense, as you need to have only a single `home` collection.

Comment: yes, of course, I have a file home.js with the code above, the a file user.js with the exact same code but the table name is User instead of home, and so on for each of my collections. so i have a variable home = new Home(driver), user = new User(driver).... those are created only once and shared thorought the project, and i query them in my request handlers

Comment: Yes, and that's what you should not do. Instead, use `const home = new Collection(driver, 'Home'), user = new Collection(driver, 'User');`. No subclasses.

Comment: agreed! But if I do this, i cannot add  **or at least i don't know how, and this is what I am looking for** specific function such as checkPasswordAsync only to user, or getMonthlySalesAsync only to orders :-(

Comment: You can create them by assigning `user.checkPasswordAsync = function(pw) { return this.… };`. Or by subclassing, i.e. `class UserCollection extends Collection { checkPasswordAsync(pw) { … } }` with `const user = new UserCollection(driver, 'User')` (which still allows you to have multiple user collections, with different drivers or table names).

Comment: Btw, unless you plan to also support synchronous methods, I would recommend to drop the `…Async` suffix from all the method names.

Comment: I first use on a machine in node 10x and if i remember correctly the async/Await wasn't available at the time... since then I kept the same snippet, It is past due time for it to get an upgrade :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I think I found the solution.

First I create a 'generic' **CollectionModel** file like this

```
module.exports = function (Table) {
  return function (driver) {
    this.driver = driver;

    this.getByIdAsync = function (_id) {
      return this.driver.then((driver) => driver.getByIdAsync(Table, _id));
    };

    this.updateAsync = function (value) {
      return this.driver.then((driver) =>
        driver.updateAsync(Table, value, value._id)
      );
    };

    this.deleteAsync = function deleteAsync(_id) {
      return this.driver.then((driver) => driver.deleteAsync(Table, _id));
    };

    this.deleteAllAsync = function deleteAllAsync(criteria) {
      return this.driver.then((driver) =>
        driver.deleteAllAsync(Table, criteria)
      );
    };

    this.findAllAsync = function findAllAsync(criteria) {
      return this.driver.then((driver) => driver.findAllAsync(Table, criteria));
    };

    this.findOneAsync = function findOneAsync(criteria) {
      return this.driver.then((driver) => driver.findOneAsync(Table, criteria));
    };

    this.saveAsync = function (value) {
      return this.driver.then((driver) => driver.saveAsync(Table, value));
    };

    this.setAsync = function setAsync(id, values) {
      const update = { $set: values };
      return this.driver
        .then((driver) => driver.partialUpdateAsync(Table, update, id))
        .then(() => Promise.resolve(true));
    };
    
  };
};
```

This will take a TableName as input and generate the root for all my model.js file. So a model file with no extras methods would look like this for the Home collection.

```
const Table = "Home";

const Model = require("../tools/mongo/CollectionModel");

let model = Model(Table);

module.exports = model;
```

and if a model requires extra method such as user for example, i can add them like this :

```js
const Table = "Users";

const Model = require("../tools/mongo/CollectionModel");

let model = Model(Table);


/***************
 * EXTRAS
 ****************/
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

model.prototype.checkPassword = function (user, password) {
  // I can access this.driver her to query my db.
};

/***************
 * END OF EXTRAS
 ****************/

module.exports = model;
```

that's actually pretty sweet and decrease a lot the numbers of line of my code :)

thanks to @Bergi for the idea...

Note that in order to use the driver I have to call in the extra method this.driver and to do so, one must only use the method.something = ()=>{} aka delegate style method. the full model.somethig = function() {} doesn't change context and so doesn't let me access my db driver.

Comment: Why take `driver` and `Table` as parameters to two separate functions? Also notice that if you don't define your methods on the prototype, you can just refer to `driver` by closure instead of using `this.driver`.

Comment: mainly to keep the changes to the minimal, the rest of my app except, when they import the home.js file to receive a function that take ta Promise<MongodBDriver> as a parameter. I could change that but it will requiere to change the rest of my app, instead I created a generator function that return a function as expected by the rest of the code. I keep a file by collection, in each file I define the table name a generate the assocciated model, I can then append to it extra function if I need. I agree it's not extra clean... but at least it's better and it doesn't break anything.

Comment: I'd still recommend to write one `class Collection { constructor(tablename, driver) { … } … }`, then make that curried helper `export const model = tablename => driver => new Collection(tablename, driver);` use it.

Comment: So i created a class Collection as you said https://gist.github.com/fburel/4f4a10ebda8ad16f53b8bfc9a99697cf but I don't know how to use it in my code and how to make subclass of it to add methods :/

Comment: Put `class UserCollection extends Collection { customMethod() { … } … }` in the user model file, then `export const userModel = driver => new UserCollection('user', driver)` instead of `export const userModel = model('user');`.